# Trying to add a calculation involving lags into a new dataframe column

Tags: r

I'm trying to do something extremely simple, but I can't work out how to do it.

Basically this:

[image: Excel formula]

Where `A` and `B` are columns in a data frame.

If I use:

```
df$B <- lag(df$B,1) + df$A
```

It obviously results in `NA` because there is no lag of `B` before row 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
     mutate(B = accumulate(A, `+`))
```

---

Or it could be just `cumsum`

```
df %>%
    mutate(B = cumsum(A))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A= c(10, 9, 3, 1, 7))
```

Comment: I saw when you first replied that you had lag(, default) or something, can you show me it again?  cumsum absolutely works for this example, so thanks, and i can't believe i have been overcomplicating it so much lol. but in the future i'd like to know how to deal with lags in data frames better.  thanks

Comment: @JamesJones  That was wrong.  Earlier, I thought you had a column B, but you only have A and it is recursively added

Comment: Okay thanks. Quick question using mutate and pipes. If i use df %>% mutate(B = cumsum(A)) like in your example, it just prints it but does not actually update the data. I can use df <- df %>% mutate... and it will, but i'm wondering why it's not updating manually.

Comment: @JamesJones  You need to assign it as you showed.  Otherwise, you can use `%<>%` from `magrittr`. i..e `library(magrittr); df %<>%mutate(..`